# VS Code Terminal panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have, accidentally, managed to access a feature in VS Code where new terminals show up in a separate panel to the right of the integrated terminal.

This seems like a nice feature, but I wish to disable it again.

How can this be done? See pictures below.

[image: Create new terminal]
[image: Terminal panel]

Kind regards /K

Comment: Use `CTRL+,`, and type `terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled`

Comment: Many thanks! This was hard to find when I did not know what the feature was called! /K

Comment: It only took me 5 mins (or less...)